# Golden Ratio in C?

Tags: c, fibonacci

I have written this code in C to calculate the golden ratio of Fibonacci sequence, but the program outputs nothing on screen. I can't understand what went wrong with my logic.

Can you please explain?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int fibonacci (int n){
    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return n;
    else
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
}

double fibonacci_golden_ratio(int n){
    double phi;
    phi = fibonacci(n)/fibonacci(n-1);
    return phi;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for (i=1;;i++){
        printf ("F = %d ",fibonacci(i));
        printf ("phi = %.5lf \n", fibonacci_golden_ratio(i));
        if ( fabs (fibonacci_golden_ratio(i) - fibonacci_golden_ratio(i-1)) < 0.0001 )
           break;
    }
    printf ("phi = %.5lf\n", fibonacci_golden_ratio(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with outputs nothing?

Comment: it compiles and writes only F=1

Comment: Try adding a global `count` variable, increment it on each call to `fibonacci`, and print its final value. I get 11438 calls when I run it. Fibonacci numbers can be computed very efficiently if you remember the lower value; you're recomputing them repeatedly, and then you're calling `fibonnaci()` twice in `fibonacci_golden_ratio`, and then you're calling `fibonacci_golden_ratio` four times on each iteration of your loop. It works, but it could be a **lot** more efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are performing integer division here:

```
phi = fibonacci(n)/fibonacci(n-1);
```

(as `fibonnacci` returns an `int`), to have a floating point division change the statement to:

```
phi = fibonacci(n) / (double) fibonacci(n-1);
```

Moreover, you have to start your loop with `i = 2`, i.e.,

```
 for (i=2;;i++){
```

instead of:

```
 for (i=1;;i++){
```

as `fibonacci_golden_ratio(i-1)` will compute `phi = fibonacci(0) / (double) fibonacci(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

If you call `fibonacci_golden_ratio(0)`, then it will call `fibonacci(-1)` that will loop forever.